# What happens when I read a file into a string

Tags: c++

For a small program, seen here [here](https://github.com/eike-fokken/dollar2math), I found out that with gcc-libstdc++ and clang++ - libc++ reading file contents into a string works as intended with std::string itself:

```cpp
  std::string filecontents;
  {
    std::ifstream t(file);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();
    filecontents = buffer.str();
  }
```

Later on I modify the string. E.g.

```cpp
 ending_it = std::find(ending_it, filecontents.end(), '$');
*ending_it = '\\';
 auto ending_pos
          = static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(filecontents.begin(), ending_it));
 filecontents.insert(ending_pos + 1, ")");
```

This worked even if the file included non-ascii characters like a greek lambda. I never searched for these unicode characters, but they were in the string. Later on I output the string to `std::cout`.

Is this guaranteed to work in C++17 (and beyond)?

The question is: What are the conditions, under which I can read file contents into `std::string` via `std::ifstream`, work on the string like above and expect things to work correctly.

As far as I know, `std::string` uses `char`, which has only 1 byte.
Therefore it surprised me that the method worked with non-ascii chars in the file.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but which line exactly do you think may not have defined behavior?

Comment: Code isn't reading directly into a `string`. That said, so long as you have previously set the `string` to the correct size, reading directly into it will cause no problems since C++11.

Comment: Whether the data read into the `string` is representable with whatever character encoding is being used, that's not C++'s problem.

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. I hope it helps.

Comment: You're probably reading a file encoded as UTF-8 and `std::cout` is rendering that correctly.

Comment: The point it's not if the content of the string is "faithful", but whoever takes that and renders glyphs on your monitor

Comment: Somehow I fail to state my question in a understandable manner it seems.

Comment: I find it surprising that the string works, when a utf8 char with more than one byte width is copied into it.

Comment: The contents of the `string` will be faithful. after that it's out of C++'s hands and in the hands of the terminal software that's going to render the contents. Trying to do other "`string` stuff" might not work. There could be what's seen as a terminating null in some of the source encoding's characters, mismatches when searching for a character because the ASCII value is found in a non-ASCII character, all manner of weird.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Is it the case that the multibyte chars are simply copied byte after byte into the string? So a lambda would result in two chars in the string: 0xCE 0xBB and as I simply search for $, which is in the asci part of utf8, the stuff works?

Comment: '$' is in the ASCII part, but nothing prevents the same bit pattern used by '$' from also appearing in a byte that is part of a completely different character encoded in UTF-8. A naiive search for '$' may have false positives.

Comment: Thank you! I guess you don't care for the reputation, but if you make an answer out of this, I'll accept it. Any idea, how I could guard against the false positives?

Comment: @user4581301 — ASCII codes never appear in the character codes of non-ASCII characters in UTF-8. All the bytes for non-ASCII characters have their high bit set. Other encodings aren’t so friendly.

Comment: @PeteBecker Does that mean that the operations I do in the question are safe? Sounds like it to me!

Comment: If your text is encoded in UTF-8 it’s “safe” to search for ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PeteBecker . That'll definitely be good to know at some point.

Comment: It might be worth your time to read up on [UTF-8](https://www.utf8.com), as it has many very useful design features, including the ability to be handled by older 8-bit ASCII programs that don’t know any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user4581301 and @PeteBecker for their helpful comments making me understand the problem.

The question stems from a wrong mental model of `std::string`, or more fundamentally a wrong model of `char`.
This is nicely explained [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#sizeof-char) and [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#character-vs-char).

I implicitly thought, that a char holds a "character" in a more colloquial sense and therefore knows of its encoding. Instead a char really only holds a single byte (in c++, in c its defined slightly differently). Therefore it is always well-defined to read a file into a string, as a string is first and foremost only an array of bytes.

This also means that reading a file in an encoding where a "character" can span multiple bytes results in those characters spanning multiple indices in the `std::string`.
This can be seen, when outputting a single char from the string.

Luckily whenever the file is ascii-encoded or utf8-encoded, the byte representation of an ascii character can only ever appear when encoding that character. This means that searching the string of the file for an ascii-character will exactly find these characters and nothing else. Therefore the above operations of searching for `'$'` and inserting a substring after an index that points to an ascii character will not corrupt the characters in the string.

Outputting the string to a terminal then just hands over the bytes to be interpreted by the terminal. If the terminal knows utf8, it will interprete the bytes accordingly.